# Javascript function to copy text raw data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to write a js function such that when copying certain text, it copies its raw form.
What I mean by raw is that, for example, if I want to copy: **text1** *text2*, then that js function should not copy them as: `text1 text2` but should rather copy them as `**text1** *text2*`.

I just know that I can get selected text using function: `window.getSelection()` but it doesn't copy text raw form.

Any help would be appreciated :).

Comment: Can you copy all of your code into this page please?

Comment: Javascript can be run in many different situations and contexts. Are you running JS in an html page in a browser? Or somewhere else?

Comment: I want to write a code which execute this functionality.
And I am running JS in a html page in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

In which context are you working? In html? If you want to get content from an html-element you could use `.innerHTML` or `.innerText` or the jQuery equivalents `.html()` or `.text()`.

https://api.jquery.com/html/